# How do I backup app data from a secondary account and move it to a new phone

Tags: backup, multi-user

My son has been using a rooted Galaxy S4 with Resurrection Remix Nougat 7.1.1_r6. He is under 13, so my user is the primary account, and I created a secondary account for him.  I am now switching him over to my old Nexus 9, but now that Google has accounts for kids, I have made his account the primary account on the Nexus 9.  How do I backup the app data from the secondary account on the Galaxy S4 and move it to the primary account on the Nexus 9 under a new google account?  This is what I have tried so far:

- Titanium only works in the primary account and doesn't seem to let me back up data from the secondary account.
- Helium only runs in the primary account, and doesn't seem to let me back up data from the secondary account.
- When I connect my PC to the phone, I can view photos, but I cannot view the app data directories.

Comment: You could try [tag:adb] backup while logged in with the secondary account. I've never tried it, but IIRC it should then access the data of that account. No guarantees, but worth a try. Please let us know if that worked out then.

Comment: There is similar question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50978678/150978